# Iterating through every other element in a list and returning a list with all the elements in the new order Python

Tags: python, list

`
I have a problem with my Python assignment and would appreciate any help. I can't get it right when the input is 7. The program returns [2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7] when it should return [2, 4, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7]. So 3 and 5 take the wrong positions.

"There are n players in a circle, numbered 1, 2, ..., n. Players take turns in the circle, and every other player leaves until the circle is empty. Your task is to determine the order in which the players exit.

You can assume that n is in the range 1 to 100.

Implement a function create in the file circlegame.py that forms the order."`

```
#what I have done so far
def create(n):
    result = list(range(1, n+1))
    arranged = []
  
    for i, number in enumerate(result):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            arranged.append(result[i])
    for i, number in enumerate(result):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            arranged.append(result[i])
            
    return arranged
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(create(1)) # [1]
    print(create(3)) # [2,1,3]
    print(create(7)) # [2,4,6,1,5,3,7]
```

Comment: Thats the task you were given, wheres your question?

Comment: Sorry I wrote the question in the end but edited it into the beginning now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following, although it increases complexity by using two loops:

```
def create(n):
    result = list(range(1, n+1))
    arranged = []
    start = 1
    
    while len(result) != 0:
        values = []
        for i in range(start, len(result), 2):
            values.append(result[i])
           
        # If both start and length of result are odd or both even, the next loop should start at 0, 
        # Otherwise, it should start at 1 (we ended at the last value, so skip the first value)
        start = (start+len(result)) & 1 # Update new start value: & 1 checks if odd or even
        
        for value in values:
            arranged.append(value) # Add elements to arranged
            result.remove(value) # Remove all elements from result

    return arranged
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot to understand where I went wrong.